# Using Regex on a List of File Names Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm learning python and trying to write some utility scripts to get more familiar with it. The purpose of my script is to loop through a root directory, find files with a certain extension, and then run a regular expression on the file to categorize them. The file names are all unique but have certain common bits that correspond to a category.

I've been able to loop through the root and print out the files (for my own test purposes) and append them to a list.

```
import os, glob, fnmatch

rootdir = '/test/dir/subdir/'

match = []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.txt'):
        match.append(file)
        print file
```

I'd like to run a set of regular expressions on my match[] list, and if their is a match, probably add that file to another list that would be used as a subcategory for the files. Is there a module or some functionality within python to do this?

Something along the lines of:

```
for file in list:
    if file.match(regex):
        do_stuff()
```

Thanks

Comment: You will want to use `re.match` from the `re` library  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

Comment: MikeRixWolfe's comment is basically your answer.

Comment: This really isn't a good Stack Overflow question - you've already got the concept down, and if you type "python regex match" into Google the first answer literally tells you the missing piece (the name of the library and how to use it)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, glob, fnmatch, re

rootdir = '/test/dir/subdir/'

match, re_match = [], []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.txt'):
        full_path=os.path.join(path, file)
#       match.append(file)                   # don't you want the full path here? 
        # regexs:
        if re.search(regex, file):     
             # re against the file name alone
             ...

        if re.search(regex, full_path):
             # re against the path+file name 
             ...
```